# How to host a webservice on IIS with dll

Tags: wcf, web-services, iis, iis-7, web-hosting

I need to host a webservice on IIS. I did this before where I will have an .svc(WCF) file or amsx file. But never did it with just a dll. How should I set it up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a class like so using asp.net compatability mode...

```
[ServiceContract]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode =  AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]
public class MyService    
{

//Some methods

}
```

Register the class in your global.asax file as a web service

```
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{

    public void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RegisterRoutes();
    }

    private static void RegisterRoutes()
    {
        RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("myServiceUrl", new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(MyService)));
    }
}
```

if your app was running on port 8080 you could then hit the service at

```
http://localhost:8080/myServiceUrl
```